# Data buffering from a file. code not working as intended

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer, memory-size

I am not very experienced in `C#`, but have lots of experience from other languages.

I am doing a project in `C#` where I have to read and modify large files.
For this I have coded a buffering scheme where I keep chunks of data in memory, and swap them to disk when I need to read more. I always eliminate the [0] element from the array, by moving the following elements back one position.

```
public struct TBBuffer
{
    public long offset;
    public short[] data;
    public GCHandle dataHandle;
}
//tb is a TBBuffer[], the data[] is initialized to 4096.
```

If I use a small sample file, where everything fits in the buffers allocated, everything works as intended.

Whenever I need to free up some memory for more data I do:

```
int bufIdx,bufNo;
for (bufIdx = 0; bufIdx < tb.buffer.Length - 1; bufIdx++)
{
    tb.buffer[bufIdx] = tb.buffer[bufIdx + 1];
}
bufNo = tb.Length - 1;
```

I have determined that the above code is the source of the problem, but I am unable to find out why that is so.

So my question is: Considering the `TBBuffer` struct, and its contents, does anybody have a clue why this is not working as expected ?

Is there a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: The code is a bit strange; f.ex. GCHandle doesn't make much sense to me. If I understand your question correctly, you're actually looking for memory mapped files? They are supported in C#.

Comment: "does anybody have a clue why this is not working as expected" You haven't explained what "not working as expected". We don't know what you expect, given you don't explain you code (we only know what it does. However it looks like you are rewriting (a really bad version) of the MMF libraries.

Comment: By the way, you never ever ever seem to be "freeing up some memory". `tb.buffer` is still allocated for the full size of your array. You also seem to be copying large chunks of memory all over the place instead of accessing the data directly (you shift memory 1 address at a time for a large chunk of memory). As far as I can tell you actually don't have any real world experience in OOP.

Comment: @TomTom It looks like Dan is a C programmer.

Comment: Well, a C programmer that never used any of the non-C standard methods. Memory mapped files are hardly a C# invention.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on this issue, this being my first post here, and all.
Clearification: I am not freeing up memory, as such, merely re-using the memory by swapping out the oldest buffer each time i need a new one.
"Not working" means it produces wrong results, I am trying to figure out whether shifting the buffers around like that is breaking c# somehow.
As for lack of OOP experience you are right.
No, I am not a C programmer.

Comment: @TomTom I dont know what that comment is supposed to mean. I developed my first programmes in 1978.... Just because my experience does not include OOP doesn't mean I can't code at all.

Comment: @DanWulff Hi Dan. I hope you don't take our comments too negatively. However, having no OOP experience is going to very much affect your ability to use C#.  I am a professional C# programmer and I haven't used a `for` loop in years. I'd advise you repost your broader question on what you are trying to process, and we can show you how to write it in OOP. As it stands, we don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for array resize?

```
  Array.Resize(ref tb.buffer, newSize);
```

Just show up your intention to .Net and let it do the work (in the efficient way) for you.

Comment: I am not using Array, just a plain short[].

Comment: short[] is an array.

Answer (score 0):

in for loop you use `tb.Length`. I think it should be `tb.buffer.Length`:

```
int bufIdx,bufNo;
for (bufIdx = 0; bufIdx < tb.buffer.Length - 1; bufIdx++)
{
    tb.buffer[bufIdx] = tb.buffer[bufIdx + 1];
}
bufNo = tb.Length - 1;
```

Comment: You are right, my bad, the code was not copied correctly. I have updated the original post with that change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem... Rather embarrasing, but the problem was that the data[] of the very last buffer would point at the same as the next-to-last after I did my for () move stunt. After adding a tb.buffer[bufNo].data=new short[4096]; statement everything is back to normal. Thank you for your time, and all the constructive feedback. I will be looking into memory mapped files to see whether this feature will be a better option.